# Is it a must to boot using TXT if we want to use the additional loaclities defined in TPM v1.2?

Tags: tpm

I'm confused reading the TPM specs. It says DRTM is what the new localities intended to work with. But is DRTM (TXT on intel platforms) definately required to use the localities 1 and above?

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=HbAAAQAAQBAJ&dq

Answer (score 0):

You can read about the "dependencies" at https://books.google.com/books?id=HbAAAQAAQBAJ&dq "Intel TXT for Servers". It's searchable online.